# String doesn't contain another String, but has String with same length instead

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regex for this String:
`FARM OF VEGETABLES\n  1. ONION\n     HU50BH/3440             \n`
which will check:

1. It contains `FARM OF VEGETABLES`
2. It contains `1. ONION`
3. It doesn't contain `HU50BH/3440`, but contain String with same length

Regex that I'm trying:

```
[\w\W]*((FARM OF VEGETABLES)[\w\W]*(1. ONION)[\w\W]*^(?!HU50BH/3440).{11}$[\w\W]*)[\w\W]*
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something like `s.matches("(?s).*?FARM OF VEGETABLES\\s+1\\. ONION(?!.*HU50BH/3440).{11}.*")`? Validate a string where the strings you mention can come one after another only?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for help. This approach is working for me:
"FARM OF VEGETABLES\n  1. ONION\n     HU50BH/3440             \n".matches("(?s).*?FARM OF VEGETABLES\\s+1. ONION(?!.*HU50BH/3440).{11}.*")

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, but when i'm changing {11} to some another it's still working, but shouldn't

Comment: So, you only allow 11 chars after `ONION`? `s.matches("(?s).*?FARM OF VEGETABLES\\s+1\\. ONION(?!.*HU50BH/3440).{11}")`? Then, do you want to allow `FARM OF` only at the beginning of the string? Then you need to also remove `.*?` at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading your question and the comments, I came up with this one.
Hope it helps:

```
.*(FARM OF VEGETABLES).*(ONION).{7}(?!HU50BH\/3440).*
```

EDIT: If you want to ensure it is 11 characters, you can modify it in a similar approach as this one:

```
.*(FARM OF VEGETABLES).*(ONION).{7}(?!HU50BH\/3440)(\S{11})\s.*
```

Use `\S` to get any character but whitespace {11} times to match the length, then afterward look for the whitespace with `\s`.

Here is a regex101 link to show the results:
https://regex101.com/r/SxNQfx/2

Comment: Glad to have helped